# Counter in state hook not incrementing

Tags: reactjs, state

I am trying to add a component every time a link is clicked.I would like to pass the count to the other component every time it is rendered.

ChildComponent contains an input textbox. On page load, there will be one text box and the user can add multiple textboxes by clicking on Add Another link

My code is,

```
const [count,setCount] = React.useState(0);
const [childComp, addComponent] = React.useState([  <ChildComponent
        content={content}
        count ={count}
        onChange={onChange}
        value={value}/>]);
const addAnother = (event)=>{
        event.preventDefault();
        setCount(count + 1);
        console.log('count here:', count);
    addComponent([
      ...childComp,
      <ChildComponent
            content={content}
            count ={count}
            onChange={onChange}
            value={value}
            />
        ]);
    }

    return(
        <div className={`${classname}__add-another-container`}>
                {childComp.map(child => child)}
        </div>
                    
        <div className={`${classname}__add-another-element`} onClick={(e) => addAnother(e)}>
            <span className={`${classname}__span-text`}>
                <label>Add Another</label>
            </span>
        </div>
    )
        
    }
```

When I console log, the count is always 0. Please can someone help me resolve this issue. I am very new to react and not able to understand why this is happening.

[image]

Comment: Other than state updates are asynchronous (i.e. you can't immediately log them and expect to see the value from the *next* render cycle) where else are you expecting to see it updated? What is `addComponent` and `ChildComponent`? Can you update your question to include that code? It looks like you are creating components and pushing them into an array, but it isn't clear why.

Comment: @Drew Reese - updated the code with an explanation.

Comment: Ok, had to create a small demo from your snippet to prove what I suspected; each new element gets a copy of the state `count` enclosed with it when it's appended to the state `childComp` array. The count *is* incremented, but that happens *after* the new component is added to the array, i.e. 0,0,1,2,3,... Typically in react storing components in state is an anti-pattern. I don't know if you simply want the same `count` to be passed to each or if that is just a weird thing you were testing. Where are the input values being stored? Typically you'd keep an array of input values.

Comment: Thanks Drew Reese. I am using the count as a textbox id in the child component. How do you recommend I approach this scenario? Ideally I would like to have one child component on load(count=0) and increment every time the link is clicked, Can you share a code snippet that could help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of storing react components in state, store just state; in this case an array of input values. You can then map this state to the UI you want rendered, i.e. the components with input fields.

Given *some* child component with an input field

```
const ChildComponent = ({ id, value, onChange }) => (
  <>
    <div>Id: {id}</div>
    <input id={id} type="text" value={value} onChange={onChange} />
  </>
);
```

An example component managing inputs. You *could* use a separate `count` state but this comes with an extra caveat around state management and synchronicity; I find it easier to use a utility function (*such as uuid*) to generate unique ids without much hassle.

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { v4 as uuidV4 } from "uuid";

const App = () => {
  const [inputs, setInputs] = useState([
    {
      id: uuidV4(),
      value: ""
    }
  ]);

  const addAnother = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    setInputs((inputs) => [
      ...inputs,
      {
        id: uuidV4(),
        value: ""
      }
    ]);
  };

  const onChange = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const { id, value } = e.target;
    
    setInputs((inputs) =>
      inputs.map((input) =>
        input.id === id
          ? {
              ...input,
              value
            }
          : input
      )
    );
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div>
        {inputs.map((props) => (
          <ChildComponent key={props.id} {...props} onChange={onChange} />
        ))}
      </div>

      <button type="button" onClick={addAnother}>
        Add
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

[image: Edit array of input values demo]

## Using a `count` state.

Key difference here is to use an `useEffect` hook to react to the `count` state updating. The effect hook runs once when the component is mounted (id 0), and then again each time the `count` state value is updated.

```
const App = () => {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);
  const [inputs, setInputs] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    setInputs(inputs => [...inputs, {
      id: count,
      value: ""
    }])
  }, [count]);

  const addAnother = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    setCount(c => c + 1);
  };

  const onChange = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const { id, value } = e.target;
    console.log("id", id, "value", value);
    setInputs((inputs) =>
      inputs.map((input) =>
        input.id === id
          ? {
              ...input,
              value
            }
          : input
      )
    );
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div>
        {inputs.map((props) => (
          <ChildComponent key={props.id} {...props} onChange={onChange} />
        ))}
      </div>

      <button type="button" onClick={addAnother}>
        Add
      </button>
    </div>
  );
};
```

[image: Edit counter-in-state-hook-not-incrementing]